# Rows more narrow than the UITableView itself

Tags: ipad, ios, uitableview

How can I create a UITableView with grouped style such that the cells are a different width than the table view is?

For instance, the table view is width 768 (iPad width) but I want the cells to be only 500 wide.

Comment: Why not just make the whole table view 500 wide, or do you want section headings that are wider for some reason?

Comment: I want the background color of the UITableView to cover my whole iPad screen, but I don't want the cells to be that wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What middaparka said in his comment, with the parent view the same background color as the uitableview:

```
myTableView.superview.backgroundColor = myTableView.backgroundColor;
// Not tested, should work though.
```

Comment: does not work. I'd like the entire background of my view to be the color of the background of the uitableview

Comment: `myTableView.backgroundColor` is probably nil because it has not been explicitly set.  Try `[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply create a UITableView that was 500 wide but had a transparent background. You could then put whatever background you want behind that in a UIImageView, etc.

Something like...

```
[myTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[myTableView setBackgroundView:nil];
[myTableView setOpaque:NO];
```

...should hopefully do the trick.

Comment: this does work well! however, do you know of any way to get the default color for the background on a uitableview grouped style on the iPad

Comment: @reising1 Not that I can think of. (You could just do a screen grab from with Xcode or from the simulator and check the colo(u)r in that.)

Comment: well, it's not one consistent color. it's like a gradient.